# How to drop certain Pandas columns, but keeping repetitions from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm parsing some data from a CSV into a proper SQL database.

Let's say I have

```
PersonId  PersonName   TripId

21          Joe        634
34          Hannah     853
34          Hannah     952
54          Ronnie     153
```

As a dataframe in pandas. But I'm turning this data into a **Person** and **Trip** table in SQL. So, I'm making the relation that a **Person** (primary key Name and Id) is able to travel 0 or more times. So, I need to drop based on *PersonId* and *PersonName*, and keep the *TripId* as it is going to be my external key. Once It's done, my result would be:

```
PersonId  PersonName   TripId

21          Joe        634
34          Hannah     853, 952
54          Ronnie     153
```

So, Hannah would not be repeated. How do I do this?

Comment: `df.groupby(['PersonId', 'PersonName'], as_index=False)['TripId'].agg(','.join)` should do the trick. If TripId is a column of ints, then cast it first: `.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))`

Comment: Hey @cs95, sorry to bother ya, but that answer did not work out in my code. Like, I checked Pandas documentation and It makes total sense (thanks for pointing It out to me) but once coding It, nothing happened. The dataset on my original question is an oversimplification, my real pandas dataframe has other columns too. Tried doing the same thing you showed, but using ".first()" after the groupby command, to keep the first occurrence of the other columns data, but nothing happened. You have any idea why? Since your comment sounds like exactly what I asked for, maybe you would know I guess.

Comment: can you explain why it did not work? what was the error, etc. Does the real data have nans?